# Multi selected values insert to database

Tags: php, mysql

Hi ive been looking around the site for fixes on my current problem. im working on a page where you have multiple selection and all selected information has to be stored in a Sql database but each selected in the multiselect has to be on its own line while the other parameters stays current.

```html
<form action="OpretRen.php" method="POST">
   <select name="area">
    <option value="Christiansminde">Christiansminde</option>
    <option value="Boulevarden">Boulevarden</option>
    </select>
    
    <select name="rum[]" multiple="multiple">
        <option value="Værelse 3">Værelse 3</option>
        <option value="Værelse 5">Værelse 5</option>
        <option value="Værelse 7">Værelse 7</option>
        <option value="Værelse 9">Værelse 9</option>
        <option value="Værelse 11">Værelse 11</option>
        <option value="Værelse 13">Værelse 13</option>
        <option value="Værelse 15">Værelse 15</option>
        <option value="Værelse 17">Værelse 17</option>
        
      </select>
   <input type="date" name="dato">
 <input type="hidden" name="ren" value="">
<input type="checkbox" name="ren" value="Skal rydes op"> Skal Rengøres <br>
      
  <input type="submit" name="opret">
</form>
```

for example you should be able to choose the location "Boulevarden" multiple rooms ex "værelse 3, værelse 11" a date and it should create 2 lines in the database 1 line with "værelse 3" and one with værelse 11 while the location and the date stays the same.

here is my php

```
$Area = $_POST['area'];
$Rum = $_POST['rum'];
$Dato = $_POST['dato'];
$ren = $_POST['ren'];

// indsætter information til databasen
$sql = "INSERT INTO `oprydning`(`Bygning`, `Rum`, `Dato`, `Rent`) VALUES ('{$Area}','{$Rum}','{$Dato}','{$ren}')";
```

i tried all kinds of solution found on google and online but nothing worked, if anybody out there has an idea how this might work please help :)

Answer (score 0):

If you create a `var_dump($_POST);` you'll notice that the multiselect creates an array in `$_POST['rum']` with a key for each selection.
If you create your PHP code to loop through this you can add multiple rows while the rest stays the same.

```
<?php
$Area = $_POST['area'];
$Dato = $_POST['dato'];
$ren = $_POST['ren'];

$lastKey = key( array_slice( $_POST['rum'], -1, 1, TRUE ) );

$sql = "INSERT INTO `oprydning`(`Bygning`, `Rum`, `Dato`, `Rent`) VALUES ";
foreach($_POST['rum'] as $k=>$Rum){
    $sql .= "('{$Area}','{$Rum}','{$Dato}','{$ren}')";
    if($k !== $lastKey){
      $sql .= ',';
    }
}
// Run $sql
```

However, I recommend you to read some best-practises and tutorials.

Comment: when i use your code it still wont work,  i the following errors


Warning: array_slice() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\skolehjem\OpretRen.php on line 209

Warning: key() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\skolehjem\OpretRen.php on line 209

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\skolehjem\OpretRen.php on line 212
Error: INSERT INTO `oprydning`(`Bygning`, `Rum`, `Dato`, `Rent`) VALUES
and Sql syntax error

Comment: @Phillipfyhn Did you select multiple options? Did you change your htmlcode? Could you create a var_dump($_POST); and share the output?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
foreach ($Rum as $item) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `oprydning`(`Bygning`, `Rum`, `Dato`, `Rent`) VALUES ('{$Area}','{$item}','{$Dato}','{$ren}')";

    //insert $sql in db

}
```

this will create a new record in you db for each value in your $Rum Array, like you want.

Comment: ive tried your answer but end up getting theese errors :

Notice: Undefined index: Rum in C:\xampp\htdocs\skolehjem\OpretRen.php on line 209

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\skolehjem\OpretRen.php on line 209

Notice: Undefined variable: sql in C:\xampp\htdocs\skolehjem\OpretRen.php on line 214

Warning: mysqli::query(): Empty query in C:\xampp\htdocs\skolehjem\OpretRen.php on line 214

Notice: Undefined variable: sql in C:\xampp\htdocs\skolehjem\OpretRen.php on line 217

Comment: @Phillipfyhn updates my answer `foreach ($Rum as $item)`